# NestJS Fastify Authentication

Tags: passport.js, nestjs, fastify, nestjs-fastify

So I replaced ExpressJS with Fastify, but my problem is Nest-Passport doesn't support fastify, do we have an alternative for Nest-Passport? or any solutions on how to secure RestAPI in nestJS using a token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no immediate Fastify NestJJS authentication package I'm aware of (I'm sure there's something out there), but [I do have a sample of JWT authentication with Fastify and NestJS **without** Passport](https://github.com/jmcdo29/fastify-jwt). The idea is to make use of Nest's `@nestjs/jwt` package or just `jsonwebtoken` directly, and create the auth tokens with that instead of delegating to Passport. This is actually the kind of approach I prefer, as I find Passport to be a bit too mystical sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

I dont kown if this is the correct manner. But if I change the default jwt extractor

> `ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken`

([described within the doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication) ) by a custom one it works.

```
const fromFastifyAuthHeaderAsBearerToken = (request: FastifyRequest): string => {
const auth = request.headers['authorization'];
const token = auth?.split(' ')[1];
return token;
}
```

Comment: This would be the correct link
https://github.com/mikenicholson/passport-jwt#writing-a-custom-extractor-function

Comment: You can also use it like in code like JWT strategy 
 ```jwtFromRequest: (request: fastify.FastifyRequest) => {
        console.log('As it is if not signed', request?.cookies?.Authentication);
        console.log('After unsigning the cookie', request?.unsignCookie(request.cookies?.Authentication));
}```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and found the following workaround do the trick for me:

At the main.ts file in src directory I just added the following code after creating the app object (NestFactory.create...)

```js
app.getHttpAdapter()
        .getInstance()
        .addHook('onRequest', (request, reply, done) => {
            reply.setHeader = function (key, value) {
                return this.raw.setHeader(key, value);
            };
            reply.end = function () {
                this.raw.end();
            };
            request.res = reply;
            done();
        });
```

This solved my issue.

I found it at : https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5702